# Nginx file upload error - too big file

Tags: php, nginx

i have nginx on centOS distro. Everything is configured to upload files fine for me..

- in etc/php.ini (dont know why on centos this file is in root of etc but its working) i have **upload_max_filesize** 60M, **client_max_body_size** 80M and **post_max_size** 80M.

Other files like nginx server configuration have these upload directives too.

But when I'm uploading a 1mb file nginx is erroring 413 Request Entity Too Large.
My web app is showing that server have 60mb file limit like info.php file.
I did a reboot, nginx reload, restart, php reload.

I have checked everything on stackoverflow and net to fix this but nothing helped.

Nginx logs: Nginx is showing that user is trying to upload bigger file than limit.

There is a pdf of my **info.php** file: http://docdro.id/YAylJcO

Answer (score 2):

Have you edited your nginx.conf.
Add `client_max_body_size xxM` inside the server section, where xx is the size (in megabytes) that you want to allow.

Comment: This helped, thank you!! i filled there only upload max and post max. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

By default, nginx is configured to allow a client maximum body size of 1MB. The files you are uploading (~8MB) are larger than 1MB, which is why  the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error is being returned.

To fix this issue, simply edit **nginx.conf** and add a `client_max_body_size` configuration like so:

```
    ######################
    # HTTP server
    ######################
    server {
        ...
        listen       80;
        server_name  xxxx.com;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        ...
    }
```

If you have HTTPS configured as well, be sure to add `client_max_body_size` there as well:

```
    ######################
    # HTTPS server
    ######################
    server {
        ...
        listen       443 default_server ssl;
        server_name  xxxx.com;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        ...
    }
```

reload your server and you should be good!

**[server]$** `sudo service nginx reload`

---

More info on `client_max_body_size` here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

> Syntax:   client_max_body_size size;
>
> Default: client_max_body_size 1m;
>
> Context:  http, server, location
>
> Sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body, specified in
>   the “Content-Length” request header field. If the size in a request
>   exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error
>   is returned to the client. Please be aware that browsers cannot
>   correctly display this error. Setting size to 0 disables checking of
>   client request body size.